# Wrapping matched string in an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hashtag

I'm implementing hashtags in my app i use ionic angularjs, im trying to match what's in the string and wrap them around an anchor in the string have a data model like this:

```
    {id:1, tags:["cool","love"], message: "i am #cool and i #love you"}
```

Lets say for example view is like this:

```
      <p> i am #cool and i #love you</p>
```

How do i implement this

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the magic of Regex!

Regex is your one-stop shop for text matching! Have a look at in action:

```
function linkHashtag(text) {
  return text.replace(/#[a-z]+/g, "<a href=\"/api/hastag/$&">$&</a>\")
}
```

When fed text with hashtags in it, it will replace them with a link to the hashtag specific url! Isn't that just dandy!

Hope this is useful for you